# How to enable databinding in kotlin

Tags: android

When I have enabled data binding I have seen the error every time and 'ActivityMainBinding' class was not created. I also use this options like (clean project and rebuild project) but binding class not generated. when I using java it's generated binding class fine.

## app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.test"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
//    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$androidPluginVersion"

}
```

## project.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.61'
    ext.androidPluginVersion = "3.2.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$androidPluginVersion"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

## MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)            
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If I am wrong then suggest me what should I do.

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow community! I was randomly selected to review your first question. Please provide as much information as possible (full error message, screenshot, difference between your setup/error message to the question that you referenced, etc) to encourage and make it easy for others to help you.

Comment: Hey @Waruyama, How to add full code in stackoverfolow site

Comment: For Kotlin you can only insert the code as text that is formatted in code style. Working examples/snippets are only possible for Javascript/CSS/HTML.

Comment: Look at my updated answer

Comment: Look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `DataBinding` you should add `<layout>` tag on your `XML`. If you are not adding this tag the expected binding class not generated.

Try with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</layout>
```

After adding this rebuild your project. Then you can get the expected binding class.

Now you can use this

```
val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

if you'll do this:

```
val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

you should add the layout tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
enter code here
</layout>
```

Comment: Hey @Archie G. Quiñones, thanks for rply,i have already added these line but i getting same error.

Comment: The '3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause' isnt actually an error. That is related to kotlin kapt. I believe they will be fixing that in the future. Ignore it for now there should be no problem with your code.

Comment: But 'ActivityMainBinding' class is not generated and i am also creating new activity ,but it's not generated binding class.

Comment: Then your problem isn't related to this. Provide more information.

Comment: you should probably post you activity and your layout.

Comment: Hey @Archie G. Quiñones, i am using this code exactly
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)

apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
and also Implement this dependecies:-
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

Comment: Please update your question. It is not easy to understand that code in this comment Section.

Comment: Hey @Archie G. Quiñones, I am updating my question and i have also provide more details please check.

Comment: But 'ActivityMainBinding' class cannot be resolved. 'ActivityMainBinding' class not found.

Comment: Post your layout xml.

Comment: Hey @Archie G. Quiñones, please check xml also